# $f(x)$ is a differentiable function for $x\in[a,b]$, and $f'(a)=f'(b)$, prove: there is a $\theta$ such that...

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

$f(x)$ is a differentiable function for $x\in[a,b]$  ($f'(x)$ may not continuously), and $f'(a)=f'(b)$, prove: there is a $\theta$ such that 
$$f'(\theta)=\frac{f(a)-f(\theta)}{a-\theta}$$

I think we should be using the Intermediate Value Theorem to solve, but i hava not idea how to get the key point, please help me.

Comment: It is [Flett's theorem](http://people.math.sc.edu/girardi/m555/current/hw/MVT-Flett.pdf) (1958).

Comment: thank you for your cite, I would like put the snap of the proof in the blow.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your cite, I would like put the snap of the proof in the blow.

[image: A proof of Flett Mean Value Theorem]